# How to apply a method on JSP code before or during HTML rendering?

Tags: java, jsp, rendering

I know that JSF supports HTML 5 adding attributes under the prefix `jsf` defined like this:

```html
<html ... xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
<!-- more facelets code here -->
<input type="email" name="email" required="required" <!-- HTML 5 data -->
       jsf:id="email" value="#{reservationBean.email}" /> <!-- JSF integration via "jsf:id" attribute -->
```

And then before generating the HTML, JSF can process this and build its tree view and create the proper components `UIComponents`.

Is it possible to apply something like that for JSP? In this way, I could add some metadata to the elements like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" required="required"
    myDescriptor:id="someId" />
```

And then process all components that have `myDescriptor:id` attribute before rendering the HTML? I haven't found anything yet on this subject.

Comment: I wonder if much has changed since        http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/06/09/jsf.html